# Close keyboard on click outside of EditText in fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, listener

I have a fragment containing an EditText for search input and a ListView. I've got the search part working, but now I want to close the keyboard when the user clicks the on the screen outside of the EditText. I'd also like to consume the click event (because it is a ListView, if I don't consume the click event the user may accidentally click on a ListView item they didn't want to open)

I know how to do this in an activity, but it seems to be different for fragments.

What I've tried so far:

- Implement `View.OnClickListener` in the fragment and implement onClick as such:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
      System.out.println("onClick true");
      if (!(v instanceof EditText)) {
          InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.
                  INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
          if (getActivity().getCurrentFocus() != null) {
              imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

This never seemed to post "onClick true" when I clicked.

- Override onTouchEvent in the fragment's activity and implement onTouchEvent as such:

  ```
  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.
              INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
          imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
      }
      return true;
  }
  ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right you can try to use a OnFocusChangeListener:

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            final InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            if (inputManager != null && !hasFocus) {
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocusedView.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        }
    });
```

This is just a sample, but maybe it points into the right direction.